# Bash check if svn reachable

Tags: bash, svn

I'm creating a bash script that does checkouts for me using whiptail.
I've got it all working but I'd like to check if i can reach svn before showing a menu etc.

Currently I'm going to do svn ls svn://host and check if the responce is equals svn: Unknown hostname 'host'. if so exit / show msg.

Is there a better way to do this using shell commands?

Grtz Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution seems to be good enough, because if you're going to do checkout, it's guaranteed that **svn** is installed on the system. So there are no additional requirements only to check if the remote port is open.

However, another possible solution would be to use **netcat** which is installed on most UNIX-like systems:

```
#! /bin/sh

TIMEOUT=2 # in seconds
HOST=$1
PORT=$2

$(nc -z -w ${TIMEOUT} ${HOST} ${PORT}) || \
    exit 1 # Port is closed

# Port is open, continue processing
```

The benefit from the **netcat**-based script is that the timeout value prevents us from waiting a lot of time on ports protected with *DROP* firewall rules.

Comment: my solution works at the moment but yours looks more promising. Mine feels kinda iffy using substring & string compare. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Its working now. I did it like this:

Comment: nc -z -w ${timeout} ${host} ${port} 2> $tmp > /dev/null;
check=$(<$tmp)

if [ "$check" != "" ]; then
  whiptail --title "Error" \
  --msgbox "Svn host [$host] on port [$port] is not reachable" 8 78
  exit
fi

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to check the command output.. just the status should be sufficient.

```
#!/bin/sh

svn info ${SVN_URL}
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "svn command failed: unable to access ${SVN_URL}";
    exit 1;
fi

#else continue svn server appears to be ok
```

The advantage of this is it will also fail on a miss typed url.

cheers